# Perturbation of matrix proof

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, perturbation-theory, condition-number

If anyone could help me with this problem it would be great. I am very lost on this. Thanks.. In trying to figure this out, I learned that [image].

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $\delta \mathbf x = A^{-1}\;\delta \mathbf b$, so that
$$
\|\delta \mathbf x\| = \|A^{-1}(\delta\mathbf b)\| \leq \|A^{-1}\|\|\delta \mathbf b\|\\
\|\mathbf b\| = \|A \mathbf x\| \leq \|A\| \|\mathbf x\| \implies \|\mathbf x \| \geq \frac{\|\mathbf b\|}{\|A\|}
$$

Comment: I'm sorry I am still not seeing where to go with this...

Comment: If $a \leq c$ and $b \geq d$, then $a/b \leq c/d$